# Change the background image of a Button when pressed using VisualStateManager

Tags: silverlight, xaml, windows-phone-7

I have this button :

```
<Button x:Name="PrevAdIcon" Tag="-1" Visibility="Collapsed" Width="80" Height="80" Click="PrevAd">
    <Button.Background>
        <ImageBrush AlignmentY="Top" Stretch="None" ImageSource="/Images/prev.png"></ImageBrush>
    </Button.Background>
</Button>
```

How can I change the background to `/Images/prev-selected.png` when a user pressed the button ? It'll give him a feedback, since it's a WP7 app

what I have so far (not working) :

```
<vsm:VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00"  Duration="00:00:00.0010000" Storyboard.TargetName="Background" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                    <ImageBrush ImageSource="/Images/prev-selected.png" Stretch="Fill"/>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </vsm:VisualState>
```

Comment: I don't see any reference to the background you wish to switch to  (/Images/prev-selected.png) in your code.

Comment: @Falanwe I edited. The ImageBrush ImageSource is Images/prev-selected.png

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See Peter Torr's post on "[Why can't I change the Background of my Button on a Click event?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ptorr/archive/2010/06/18/why-can-t-i-change-the-background-of-my-button-on-a-click-event.aspx)" for an example and explanation of how to do this.

Answer (score 5):

As far as I know, you can't change the value of the Source property on the Image element by using the VisualStateManager. However, you can just add two Image elements to the ControlTemplate: one for the Normal state and one for the Pressed state, and toggle the Visibility in the Pressed state.

```
<VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
    <Storyboard>
        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)" Storyboard.TargetName="Img">
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Collapsed" />
        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)" Storyboard.TargetName="PressedImg">
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Visible" />
        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
</VisualState>
```

Answer (score 3):

To add more information to Derek's answer, you should look at Gambit's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12059079/windows-phone7-create-a-custom-button-with-different-background-images-for-each) for full XAML that works