# Changing source of an Image inside of a Button template

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I have a button with an image defined in XAML like this:

```
<Button x:Name="buttonTest">
    <Button.Template>
        <ControlTemplate>
                <Border HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" >
                    <Image x:Name="imageTest" Width="57" Height="81" Source="/Images/sample.png" />
                </Border>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Button.Template>
</Button>
```

How can I change the source of the image when the button is clicked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I finally figured it out, user Gambi provided an answer in another [thread.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12059079/windows-phone7-create-a-custom-button-with-different-background-images-for-each/12060463#comment25628851_12060463)

Answer (score 0):

I would probably do this with a toggle button instead of button since it has the IsChecked property that you can base the image switch on.

First you'll need some converter to go from true/false to the image path, may as well make it a generic one that you can use over and over, add this to your project and setup an xmlns to point to it in your xaml.

```
public class BooleanSwitchConverter : DependencyObject, IValueConverter
    {
        public object TrueValue
        {
            get { return (object)GetValue(TrueValueProperty); }
            set { SetValue(TrueValueProperty, value); }
        }
        public static readonly DependencyProperty TrueValueProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("TrueValue", typeof(object), typeof(BooleanSwitchConverter), new PropertyMetadata(null));

        public object FalseValue
        {
            get { return (object)GetValue(FalseValueProperty); }
            set { SetValue(FalseValueProperty, value); }
        }
        public static readonly DependencyProperty FalseValueProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("FalseValue", typeof(object), typeof(BooleanSwitchConverter), new PropertyMetadata(null));

        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return ((bool)value) ? TrueValue : FalseValue;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

Then replace your Button with a toggle button like this using a Binding on IsChecked to pick the image.

```
<ToggleButton>
            <ToggleButton.Template>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ToggleButton">
                    <Border>
                        <Image>
                            <Image.Source>
                                <Binding Path="IsChecked" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}">
                                    <Binding.Converter>
                                        <local:BooleanSwitchConverter 
                                            TrueValue="1.jpg" 
                                            FalseValue="2.jpg"/>
                                    </Binding.Converter>
                                </Binding>
                            </Image.Source>
                        </Image>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </ToggleButton.Template>
        </ToggleButton>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a trigger like this (Used a rectangle for simplicity in the sample):

```
<Button x:Name="buttonTest" Width="200" Height="200">
    <Button.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Border HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" >
                <Rectangle x:Name="Image" Height="{TemplateBinding Height}" Width="{TemplateBinding Width}" Fill="Yellow"></Rectangle>
            </Border>
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                    <Setter TargetName="Image" Property="Fill" Value="Red"></Setter>
                </Trigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Button.Template>
</Button>
```

Comment: I get an error "Type Button is not supported in a Silverlight project".

Comment: That will only change the image when the mouse is held down on the Button, not when it's clicked.

Comment: @Kajzer try removing `TargetType="{x:Type Button}"`

Comment: @JohanLarsson I did, but then I get "The member Triggers is not recognized or accessible". Note that I am working on a Windows Phone project.

Comment: ok no idea then, looks like it would work in wpf, dunno about phone